# Check if a value is already in the table PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to check if a value is already in the table.
The structure of my table is this: 
ApplicantId = INT 
EventId = INT 
StudentId = INT

No need to use unique because these table has dependencies.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
include('../connectdb.php');

$ScholarPointId = $_GET["ScholarPointId"];
$Point = $_GET["Point"];
$ScholarId = $_GET["ScholarId"];
$EventId = $_GET["EventId"];

$verifysql = mysql_query("SELECT EventId FROM scholar_attended_events WHERE ScholarId ='$ScholarId' ");

#$resultVerify = mysql_fetch_assoc($verifysql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($verifysql);

if( $num_rows > 0 )
{
 $script = "<script>
     alert('The user has already attended this event!');
            </script>";
 header('updatescholarpoints.php');
 exit();
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE scholar_points 
SET scholar_points.Points = 
scholar_points.Points + $Point  
WHERE scholar_points.ScholarPointId = '$ScholarPointId' ") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO scholar_attended_events (EventId , ScholarId) VALUES( '$EventId' , '$ScholarId' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

}

?>
```

What I want is to check if the EventId is already in taken by the Student = StudentId. If so, then system will prompt an alert box. Otherwise, Update and Insert into respective table. How can I do this? It seems I miss something in here. If you could help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @MikeB it's not saving even though the event id is not taken by a specific student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just missing an `=` ?

```
$verifysql = mysql_query("SELECT EventId FROM scholar_attended_events WHERE ScholarId =$ScholarId ");
```

(and use PDO or mysqli, your code is really in a deprecated mode)

Comment: thanks. I forgot to add, but when it's fixed it's not getting the alert message? And even though I added a value that's not taken yet by the user, it's not saving.